# Message Broker server in .NET (CoreCLR/DNX)

Tags: c#, protocols, amqp, dnx, messagebroker

I want to know, Have we a Messaging System like JMS in .NET Platform ?

I see something like RabbitMQ but that server wrote in Erlang, I want a .NET server

Can anyone guide me how can I write a server based on AMQP protocol ?
Can anyone guide me which library implemented AMQP 1.0 protocol in C# ?
I think at first I must have amqp protocol in .NET

Please help me.

Comment: https://goo.gl/2yFbj4

Comment: The messaging system for .Net is WCF. I think you should use a message broker that accomodates all the different messaging platforms used in your environment. I wouldn't choose a broker that only supports one messaging system and force the clients to adapt. In a .Net environment I'd consider BizTalk as the message broker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server doesn't need to be written in the same language as you are using. There is a .net client for RabbitMQ
https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet.html

If you need a .net server. you can use NServiceBus. NServiceBus is fully AMQP compliant
http://particular.net/nservicebus

http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/07/nservicebus-4-0

So to summarise - both the RabbitMQ and NServiceBus .net clients are AMQP compliant as are the servers.

Comment: You right I know about NServiceBus but that is not work on CoreCLR (DNX) / I works with RabbitMQ but I want to have server based on CoreCLR

Comment: I see the question has been edited now to indicate that it's coreclr/dnx that you're after. That is still in beta as far as I know. May I ask why you need it to be .net which runs on dnx?
NServiceBus runs on mono or like I said, you could use one of many other servers which will run on any OS and have .net clients.
Why must it be dnx and not mono? Why must the server be .net if there is a good .net client for it?

Comment: I agree with Cameron. A good ESB/broker will interface with anything that's out there, without tying you to any particular technology. As it hasn't been mentioned yet...IBM Integration Bus has excellent support for .Net, while allowing Java, XSLT and graphical mapping to be used as well.